# PHP Pathfinder not returning results

Tags: php

I been trying to make a PHP path finder from examples in other languages and tweaked it for my game's need but its not returning any values.

I should note - I get no errors in my error log file either so I'm guessing its a logic mistake?

Hope some one can spot it cos i cannot see the mistake =/

Code:
http://www.paste.to/NDI3MTE1

Comment: Please post your code here. Spam filters are blocking it on my end...

Comment: I couldn't it was too long for the characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just took a really short look, but:

```
function findpath($sx, $sy, $sdata) {
    if( in_array($sx, $sdata) && in_array($sy, $sdata($sx) ) ){
        ...
    }
}

$sdata = array(
           "13" => ...,               
           "14" => ...,    
           "15" => ...
);

$astar = findpath(13,15,$sdata);
```

`in_array` checks the array values, not the keys... as such, your whole function doesn't even do anything. Use `array_key_exists` for this.

Comment: Thanks i have fixed this aspect :)

Comment: Note that there's also a syntax error with $sdata($sx) in the 2nd part of the if.

Comment: yeh i switched it to square brackets -originally it wldnt allow square brackets - not it seems it does

Comment: Glancing some more over the code, there seem to be several logic mistakes. Also, it's far too much / complex to tell at glance what's wrong.

Comment: There's no need to accept this answer since it didn't actually help you in any way. I won't complain though ;)

Comment: It did get me started :P and i don't think any one else is willing to answer or even look at the code! SO credit for helping me out anyway :)